# Using Linq to find next element in subset of a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following collection

```
// The collection to query
    var stageTable = new List<Stage>
    {
    new Stage {StageId = 1, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 1},
    new Stage {StageId = 2, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 2},
    new Stage {StageId = 3, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 3},
    new Stage {StageId = 4, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 4},
    new Stage {StageId = 5, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 1},
    new Stage {StageId = 6, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 2},
    new Stage {StageId = 7, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 3},
    new Stage {StageId = 8, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 4},
    };
```

and I'm trying to construct a query that will return the next `Stage` given a `currentStage` but contained within the same subset defined by the `LifecycleId`, e.g., given `currentStage = 2` I would expect to get `Stage` with `stageId = 3` back, but with `currentStage = 4` I would expect to get `null` back since the `LifecycleId` switches to a value of `2`.

This is what I have

```
 var lifecycleId = stageTable
                .Where(x => x.StageId == currentStageId)
                .Select(x => x.LifecycleId);

 var nextStage = stageTable
                .Where(s => s.LifecycleId == lifecycleId.First())
                .SkipWhile(s => s.StageId != currentStageId)
                .Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

It appears to work, but is there a way to perform this in a single query?

Comment: Were any of the answers here what you were looking for @JamesB ?

Comment: @mjwills Decided to stick with original two lines as in my question. All solutions are interesting but not sure they offer more benefit and in some cases readability is lost.

Comment: The main benefit will be performance @JamesB . Mine or stop-cran will do it in a single pass. Ultimately your solution is fine though. _You may wish to look through the answers and decide on which you like best, in terms of marking it as the answer._

Answer (score 1):

This uses the overload of FirstOrDefault that takes a Predicate:

```
{
    var currentStageId = 3;

    // The collection to query
    var stageTable = new List<Stage> {
        new Stage {StageId = 1, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 1},
        new Stage {StageId = 2, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 2},
        new Stage {StageId = 3, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 3},
        new Stage {StageId = 4, LifecycleId = 1, StageSeqNo = 4},
        new Stage {StageId = 5, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 1},
        new Stage {StageId = 6, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 2},
        new Stage {StageId = 7, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 3},
        new Stage {StageId = 8, LifecycleId = 2, StageSeqNo = 4},
    };

    var nextStage = stageTable.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StageId > currentStageId && s.LifecycleId == stageTable.FirstOrDefault(s2=>s2.StageId==currentStageId)?.LifecycleId);
}
```

Comment: You seem to have just replaced the first linq query in the question by declaring a currentStage object rather than using `stageTable.Where(x => x.StageId == currentStageId)`. If the OP had a stage object then that first query wouldn't be needed so your answer doesn't really address the OP's problem.

Comment: @Chris I made a change that accounts for unknown LifecycleID. I'd like to ask the OP, this seems to be something you do in a loop, progressively finding the next Stage. Given that you get a Stage object out of this, how come you don't know the LifecycleId the next time around? Why don't you have the whole Stage instead of just currentStageId? This forces you to have 2 loops, first to find the LifecycleId & then to use it to find the Stage. If this list is bigger, that's a pretty expensive thing to do.

Comment: This really is the closest you're going to get to using a single query. I don't understand why it was downvoted.

Comment: You will likely find that `stageTable.FirstOrDefault(s2=>s2.StageId==currentStageId)` executes for each source row until it finds a match (so this solution may not scale super well if the row it is looking for is the one millionth row).

Comment: @mjwills he asked to do this with LINQ. IEnumerable is a forward only iterator, so that cannot be avoided. There is probably an optimization in LINQ for IOrderedEnumerable that may do a binary search but u would have to pipe it thru OrderBy. Can u suggest an optimized pure LINQ approach?

Comment: @stop-cran's solution or mine will likely solve the problem in a single pass, for example.

Comment: Yes those solutions will be more efficient & scale if the list is ordered by StageId like the sample

Comment: Looking at the those solutions more carefully, although they do use LINQ-like sematics, they rely on extra code to get that behaviour. Essentially writing new LINQ operators. The OPs request was to do this in a single expression, implying he wanted to reduce code. Besides the possible benefits of code resuse, the OPs original solution doing this in 2 lines of standard LINQ would generally be preferable to solutions writing the final expression in 1 line at the expense of writing other supporting functions.

Comment: `implying he wanted to reduce code` What brought to you that conclusion? What makes you think the objective is to reduce code vs, say, improving performance? _If the OPs objective was to reduce code, why use LINQ at all? LINQ has a **heap** of code behind the scenes._

Comment: Because he didn't mention anything about performance, just that he wanted to convert 2 lines of code into 1 line.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) then you could use code like:

```
var currentStageId = 4;

var nextStage = stageTable.SkipWhile(z => z.StageId < currentStageId)
    .Lead(1, (x, y) => new { existing = x, next = y })
    .Take(1)
    .FirstOrDefault(z => z.next?.LifecycleId == z.existing.LifecycleId)?.next;

Console.WriteLine(nextStage?.StageId);
```

`SkipWhile` will skip the data before your current row.

`Lead` will merge adjacent rows (i.e. put the current and next row together).

`Take 1` will ensure that we get only a single row (representing the current and next row together).

And `FirstOrDefault` will ensure that null is returned if the second row does not have the same `LifeCycleId` as the first row).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to get the current stage and the next stage first (regardless of cycle) and then check if the following stage is of the same cycle:

```
var nextStage = stageTable.Where(s => s.StageId >= currentStageId)   //filter out all lower values
                .OrderBy(s=> s.StageId)                              //if the list is always ordered, this could be omitted
                .Take(2)                                             //enumeration now contains the currentid and the next id
                .GroupBy(s=>s.LifecycleId)                           //only from those 2 objects -> group by the lifecycle
                .First().Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();                   //the (first) group will only contain 2 items, if the lifecycle is the same
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd introduce a method to iterate the underlying enumerable together with (possibly null) previous item:

```
public static class EnumerableExtras
{
    public static IEnumerable<Pair<T>> WithPrevious<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
        where T : class
    {
        T previous = null;

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return new Pair<T>(item, previous);
            previous = item;
        }
    }
}

public class Pair<T> where T : class
{
    public Pair(T current, T previous)
    {
        Current = current;
        Previous = previous;
    }

    public T Current { get; }
    public T Previous { get; }
}
```

One can propose following solution using this extension:

```
var nextStage = stageTable
    .WithPrevious()
    .FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.Previous?.StageId == currentStageId &&
                            pair.Current.LifecycleId == pair.Previous?.LifecycleId)
    ?.Current;
```

For value types it's possible to define alike `Pair<>` class with nullable `Previous` property.